# Regex with first line

Tags: linux, regex, sed

I want to search inside the but replacement the firsh character of line.

for example, line is this

> pool 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst maxsources 1

I want to search **pool.ntp.org** add firsh character **#**
I try something but it's not work

```
%s/pool\.ntp\.org/#/gmi
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bsh
$ cat file
pool 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst maxsources 1

$ sed -e 's/^\(.*pool\.ntp\.org\)/#\1/' file
#pool 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst maxsources 1
```

**explanation:**

```
^                   # beginning of line
  \(                  # start group 1
    .*                  # 0 or more any character
    pool\.ntp\.org      # literally
  \)                  # end group
```

**replacement:**

```
#           # character #
\1          # backreference to group 1
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation, it's very helpfull. Can you recomended any material for this subject?

Comment: @thargalin: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/urHq11/1) is a nice tool to test regex. Caution: It doesn't understand regex flavour used with sed.